# Get the name of snapshot from property using zfs get

Tags: zfs

It would like to know if it's possible to get the name of snapshot from any property.

For example, I created a property called `:uuid` with the value `c98fdd32-8a76-4bcf-a509-d298291f85f5`

If it's possible to get the name of this snapshot using the property and its value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

## Short answer:

Use `zfs get -Hpr -t snapshot -o name,value :uuid | awk '{if ($2 == "c98fdd32-8a76-4bcf-a509-d298291f85f5") print $1}'`

## Long answer/explanation:

1. You can query any ZFS property of any dataset (file system, volume, or snapshot):

   ```
   zfs get :uuid <dataset>
   ```
2. If you call it recursively with `-r` without a dataset, you will get all valid datasets:

   ```
   zfs get -r :uuid
   ```
3. To reduce it only to datasets of snapshot type, use `-t`:

   ```
   zfs get -r -t snapshot :uuid
   ```
4. Then you can only display the columns you want with `-o`, in this case the name and value columns:

   ```
   zfs get -r -t snapshot -o name,value :uuid
   ```
5. To further work with the data, you need remove the headers with `-H` and display numbers as exact values with `-p`:

   ```
   zfs get -Hpr -t snapshot -o name,value :uuid
   ```
6. This includes all values, even non-set ones (`-`), so you need to further filter the output (for example with `awk`):

   - If you just want a specific snapshot name (print every first column/name for each line where the second column/value is the specific string):

     ```
      zfs get -Hpr -t snapshot -o name,value :uuid | awk '{if ($2 == "c98fdd32-8a76-4bcf-a509-d298291f85f5") print $1}'
     ```
   - If you want all results except the empty ones (all without `-`):

     ```
      zfs get -Hpr -t snapshot -o name,value :uuid | awk '{if ($2 != "-") print $1}'
     ```
   - If you want to just have the basename, you can then further split first and second column by `@` (which is the delimiter between file system and snapshot name):

     ```
      zfs get -Hpr -t snapshot -o name,value :uuid | awk '{if ($2 != "-") print $1}' | awk -F"@" '{print $1}'
     ```

Comment: Thank you so much, really I don't want this solution but I explained myself very bad. With your explanation I can do that I want:
`zfs get -Hpr -t snapshot -o name,value :uuid | awk '{if ($2 == "c98fdd32-8a76-4bcf-a509-d298291f85f5") print $1}'`

I wanted to get name using the value of property :uuid

Comment: @icvallejo Glad it helped. I understood you, but my solution was lacking (I forgot that you want to filter for a specific value and did not read your question again), sorry for that. I will add your comment into the answer. Thanks for accepting!

Comment: This is the right way to do it today, but FYI there is also a new feature in progress called "channel programs" (https://www.slideshare.net/mobile/MatthewAhrens/openzfs-channel-programs) which would allow you to do this in a single atomic operation.